# Splitting CSV into files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for some guidance with what I am trying to do.

I have a .csv file, and in this file I want to break down each line and save it into its own text file.

I have that part working, however, when it runs I am losing the commas. I am assuming this is happening because I am converting a .csv file into a list then into a text file.

I feel there has to be a better way!

**Code**

```
def createParam():
    with open('testcsv.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        csvList = list(reader)

    for item in csvList:
        os.mkdir(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test Path\\" + item[0])
        f=open(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test Path\\" + item[0] + r"\prm.263","w+")
        f.writelines(item)
        f.close
```

**CSV**

> Store1,1080,SafehavenHumaneSociety,2904,LuckyPaws,3156,StMartinsDogRescue,4051,SalemFriendsofFelines,4088,HeartlandHumaneSociety,4118,Fortheloveofacat,6329,PeacefulPack,7710,OneVoice4Paws,7981,KeithasKittieRescue,7984,InternationalReptileRescueInc,9304,SeniorDogRescueOfOregon,9309,LovedAgainPets
>   Store2,0028,ArizonaAnimalWelfareLeague,0039,HelpingAnimalsLiveOnHALO,1468,MaricopaCountyAnimalCareandControlMCACC,4250,BuckeyeAnimalRescueKennel,5112,MASH,5957,FeathersFoundationInc,6725,ValleyHumaneSociety,7172,KitKatRescue,7627,LuckyDogRscu,7761,AZSmallDog,8114,WhoSavedWhoRescue,9160,DestinationHome,9248,AllAboutAnimals

**Clarification**: When it creates the file(s), it has all the data, but all the commas are removed so its just all 1 long line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each `item` is a list of values representing a row in the CSV, you should write it as a CSV with `csv.writer`:

```
for item in csvList:
    os.mkdir(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test Path\\" + item[0])
    with open(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test Path\\" + item[0] + r"\prm.263","w+") as f:
        csv.writer(f).writerow(item[1:])
```

Comment: This worked perfect. One semi-off-topic question... is there a way to exclude the very first index when writing that file? (remove the Store1 and Store2)

Comment: Glad to be of help. I've updated my answer to exclude the first item of each row in the output.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks again sir.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just need to load the file and read line by line (not loading it as a csv file). Each line goes to a file.

```
index = 0
with open('testcsv.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        index += 1
        with open('new_textfile_{}.csv'.format(index), 'w') as f2:
            f2.write(line)
```

If you want to save the files in some directory X, then the path in the second `with open...` should be `"X/whatever_name_{}.csv".format(index)`